# iOS application crash after updated to 10.3. Cannot add photo

Tags: ios

can anyone help me with this error?

This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's `Info.plist` must contain an `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Basically, my application can be run when using ios 9.3 but after i updated my Ios. It turn to this error.

- I already add all necessary Key into my `info.plist`

Below is my `info.plist`:

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<string></string>
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<string></string>
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string></string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} CameraAdditional Usage</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow users to add picture</string>
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} BluetoothPeripheral</string>
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Calendar Usage</string>
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Contact fetch</string>
<key>NSHealthShareUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Health Description</string>
<key>NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Health Updates</string>
<key>NSHomeKitUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} HomeKit Usage</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Use location always</string>
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Location Updates</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} WhenInUse Location</string>
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Music Usage</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Microphone Usage</string>
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Motion Usage</string>
<key>kTCCServiceMediaLibrary</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} MediaLibrary Usage</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow user to add picture from library</string>
<key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Reminder Usage</string>
<key>NSSiriUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Siri Usage</string>
<key>NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Speech Recognition Usage</string>
<key>NSVideoSubscriberAccountUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Video Subscribe Usage</string>
<key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
<string></string>
<key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
<string></string>
<key>Privacy - Calendars Usage Description </key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) calendar events</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string></string>
<key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
<string></string>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
```

Comment: Please provide the crash data

Comment: Can Please you provide Crash report

Comment: libsystem_kernel.dylib`__abort_with_payload:
    0x11716b0a0 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000209, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000209 
    0x11716b0a5 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x11716b0a8 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x11716b0aa <+10>: jae    0x11716b0b4               ; <+20>
    0x11716b0ac <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x11716b0af <+15>: jmp    0x117164caf               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x11716b0b4 <+20>: retq   
    0x11716b0b5 <+21>: nop    
    0x11716b0b6 <+22>: nop    
    0x11716b0b7 <+23>: nop

Answer (score 1):

Add this into info.plist `<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Photo Library Access Warning</string>`